# How do I completely remove the label or the label's spacing in angular-formly form?

Tags: angular-formly

Using angular-formly, I'm trying to build a form, where if the label is removed in fields json, there is no padding or spacing given to the that label in the rendered html.

Here is an example of the actual form and my 'desired' form:
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wisali/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would require a pull request to the template library's [label wrapper template](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/blob/master/src/wrappers/label.html) which would use an `ng-if` to hide the label if one is not provided.

If you don't want to deal with that, then you can choose from one of these options:

1. Set `wrapper` to `null` for the field. But you lose the other wrappers as well (like the one that adds `has-error`)
2. Create your own type that allows you to specify your own wrappers.

Both of these are demonstrated here:

https://jsbin.com/quceqi/edit?html,js,output